# Where is the robots.txt stored for a WordPress Multisite install?

Tags: multisite

Google Webmaster Tools can see it, but I can't find it. Any idea on how it's generated or where it is the file structure? I don't see the file in my root. My website is at http://mikewills.me and the robots.txt file URL is http://mikewills.me/robots.txt.

In the end, Google isn't indexing my site and I am trying to figure out how to edit the robots.txt so that indexing is allowed. I have changed the privacy option to allow indexing, but that hasn't updated the robots.txt.

Comment: Site link? robots.txt is unlikely to have anything to do with WP...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's dynamically generated by the function [`do_robots()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-includes/functions.php#L1779), which has both an action (`do_robotstxt`) and a filter (`robots_txt`). If you create a `robots.txt` file in your WordPress root, it will (probably) be served up when `/robots.txt` is requested, otherwise processing will fall back on WordPress.

Your current file looks like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:

Sitemap: http://mikewills.me/sitemaps/mikewills-me.xml.gz
```

The first two settings are appropriate for an indexable blog. So, you may just be waiting for Google at this point. Maybe you need to [request reconsideration of your site](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35843).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was under this assumption. I was scared to see the Disallow. So that is okay then?

Comment: @Mike: Yes, this is OK. What you say now is: "Hey robots whose `User-agent` match `*` (so all robots), the list of pages you cannot access is `[empty]`." Which means that they can access all pages.

Comment: Adding robots.txt to the root does not seem to work, it still serves the WordPress generated one. Is there no way to add or modify the robots.txt without installing a plug-in?

Answer (score 3):

robots.txt is dynamically created. There is no robots.txt file. Install a robot.txt plugin will solve your problem. Hope this helps